# Wake up Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, serverless

I have an existing Azure Function that is on a consumption plan

I am writing another function which will call this

Once the existing function is running, it processes files in storage account.

In order the files in my storage account to be processed, we have to manually go into the portal and "wake up" the function by navigating

Is there a way to do this via C# code?

This function is hosted on a consumption based plan

Comment: Azure Functions are automatically woken up based on their triggers (e.g. timer, http). There is no requirement to do this manually. What are the defined triggers for each of these functions at the moment?

Comment: Not sure how to check this?  One of the functions will be new one inside in a different function app.  E.g. FunctionApp1.Function1 will call FunctionApp2.Function1

Comment: If they’re written in C#, you should see the function entry point decorated with a `Trigger` attribute indicating the trigger type. You should look into the various trigger options, as e.g. a blob arriving in blob storage is one of them and might fit what you’re trying to do with a single function.

Comment: @sellotape I have a function triggered by a `BlobTrigger`, and when not used after some hours, it takes like 6min to wake up. This is horribly long and I don't event see the point to sell these unusable consumption plan. So yes, no requirement to do it manually, but if you want to avoid the user to wait 6 min to process a file, you have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this is exact solution you are looking for. I came across this article **"An Azure Function to keep other Functions/URLs warmed up"** while looking for such solution, haven't tried it yet but I will. If you try it first do post the result.

https://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2018/09/Azure-Function-Warmup-Cold-Start.html

The other approach that I came across is **"pinging a health endpoint within your Azure Functions through Azure Monitor."** Create a URL ping test. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/monitor-web-app-availability

I am in the process of trying these out. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In serverless computing, Azure functions get executed/spin up whenever you make an invoke, if you want to call another function inside a function you can  do via HTTP call.

[`Durable Functions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/) lets you write stateful functions in a serverless environment. There's nothing built-in in Function Apps to call one HTTP function from other functions without actually making the HTTP call paticularly [`Function Chaining`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-sequence).

Comment: This is fine I will call the other using a http call

Comment: yeah you can do that